# Почему в мемо уходят неверные данные?

Tags: delphi

Помогите, пожалуйста. В коде много лишнего, просто я эксперементировал, не обращайте внимания, раньше всё работало, но сейчас не понимаю, что случилось

```
procedure TForm1.sButton2Click(Sender: TObject);

var
a, b, rezult : integer;
Str1, Str2, Str3, Str4, Str5, Str6: String;
begin
Memo1.Text:=IdHTTP1.Get('http://humor-informers.ru/informer.php');
Str1:=Memo1.Text;
Delete(Str1, 1000, 0);
memo1.Text:=Str1;

Label3.Caption:= IntToStr(Length(Memo1.Lines.Text));
 Str2:=Memo1.text;
Delete(Str2, 1, 41); //120
Memo1.Text:=str2;
Label3.Caption:= IntToStr(Length(Memo1.Lines.Text));
a := StrToInt(Label3.Caption);
b := StrToInt('120');
rezult := a - b;
Delete(Str2, rezult, 120);
Memo1.Text:=str2;

Str3:=Memo1.Text;
Str6:=AnsiReplaceStr(Str3, '<br>', ' ');
Memo1.Text:=str6
```

На код компилятор не ругается, просто меня не устраивает, то что уходит в мемо. Там то недостает символов, то наоборот больше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    вот полностью рабочий код. проверяйте :)

procedure Get;
var
   rezult, poz: integer;
   Str1: String;
begin
  with F_Main do
    begin
      Memo.Text := IdHTTP.Get('http://humor-informers.ru/informer.php');
      Str1 := Memo.Text;
      poz  := Pos('<p>',Str1)+2;
      Delete(Str1, 1, poz);
      poz  := Pos('<\/p>',Str1)-1;
      rezult := Length(Str1) - poz;
      Delete(Str1, poz+1, rezult);
      Memo.Text := AnsiReplaceStr(Str1, '<br>', ' ');
    end
end;
```

Comment: еще изменил код.

Comment: оформил все отдельной процедурой на всякий случай, вдруг захотите еще куда-либо прикрутить.
И в Вашем случае, имена надо будет поменять. Я убрал индексы у компонентов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Не за что :) Всегда рад помочь)
Прошу прощения, что так затянул)